# ПредИстория или предЫстория?

Tags: орфография, приставка

Помогите разобраться, как правильно писать это слово.

Answer (score 8):

После приставок, оканчивающихся на согласную, вместо **и** пишется **ы** в соответствии с произношением, например: играть – под**ы**грать, искать – от**ы**скать, история - пред**ы**стория. Есть и исключения.См.http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/26.htm#з_03, §33. Гласные ы и и после приставок.

Comment: Можно спросить, Вы в чем-то возражаете предыдущему отвечальщику?

Comment: А зачем возражать? Это дополнение!

Answer (score 6):

И меняется на Ы после русских приставок на согласную, кроме приставок меж- и сверх-. ПредЫнфарктный, но постИнфарктный.

Comment: А Ваши примеры - это исключение ( примечание 4, §33), которое гласит: сохраняется И после иноязычных приставок и частиц дез-, контр-, пост-, суб-, супер-, транс-, пан-. Например: дезинформация, контригра, постимпрессионизм, субинспектор, суперинтендант, трансиорданский, панисламизм. 

Ср.: предынфарктный – постинфарктный (русская и иноязычная приставки).